# Device messaging using FHIR

Tags: hl7-fhir, dstu2-fhir

I am trying to define a device messaging spec that uses FHIR resources. I need to produce Observations and also record state changes of Device, DeviceComponent and DeviceMetric. The device will be ambulatory so it will need to buffer the changes  if connectivity is interrupted.

So here is my problem:
I need to record the time a change occurred on the device (firmware update, operationalStatus on/off, etc.) but the Device resources have no timestamp. Should I wrap the resource in a MessageHeader with the Device resource change in the data section of the MessageHeader and POST the message to a deviceMessage url and let the server update the proper resources? or is there something else?

Sending Observations are straight forward but I have not been able to find a device state change use case like I am describing within the FHIR documentation or discussions.

Answer (score 0):

Typically capturing information about when a change occurred, who made the change, why the change occurred, etc. is done using Provenance.  The Provenance instance might be created by the client, or it could be auto-generated by the server with contextual information based on security headers, etc.